# Chrome - javascript console not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, browser, console

I am trying to debug my code in the Google Chrome Console but everytime I select a line to evaluate it in the console I get this error message:

```
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

My code seems to be running fine as I don't get any error message.

Does anyone know why this happen?

Many thanks

Comment: I get this for any page of my website no matter what the code is. If I evaluate something like var h=0; and then h, I get the same result as above.

Comment: Your code most be doing something

Comment: That's not an error message.

Comment: I dont get any warning/error message. When the page is loaded and I highlight a piece of code, right click on it and select evaluate in console I get this message...

Comment: I actually have the same issue if I open any website, go to sources in developer tools, type in any code and evaluate it in the console: no matter what I type I get this message

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions installed?

Comment: yes, livereload, firebug and pocket

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Lines of code in console were only grey and returned nothing even for syntactically wrong lines.

Browser restart helped.